# Render only on server-side, i. e. `<server-only>` tag

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, server-side-rendering

Some of my code needs to be rendered on client side only, therefore I wrapped it in `<client-only>` tag.

However, to prevent content from jumping, I tried to render element only on server-side using this:

```
<div v-if="$isServer" class="h-nonav bg-gray-500" />
```

This does work but Vue complains that server side HTML doesn't match client side one.

This works it but sounds too hackish and causes the page to render twice:

```
<div v-if="ssr" class="h-nonav bg-gray-500" />
...
data() {
  return {
    ssr: true
  }
},
mounted() {
  this.ssr = false
},
```

Tried searching Docs but there is no `<server-only>` tag :(

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, `v-show` instead of `v-if` fixes it:

```
<div v-show="$isServer" />
```

Hope this will help me again down the road...